# Is there a Google plus SDK for Amazon devices?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-play-services

I am integrating google plus into my app and it works fine with the google_play_service library.But since this library doesn't work in amazon devices my app always crash when I share something from the Amazon devices.So it is only possible to avoid sharing in google plus when using Amazon devices or is there a workaround.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you use the Google Play Services lib, it is important to check whether the device supports the use of Google Play Services. This is done as follows:

```
private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

    context = getApplicationContext();

    // Check device for Play Services APK.
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        // If this check succeeds, proceed with normal processing.
        // Otherwise, prompt user to get valid Play Services APK.
        ...
    }
}

// You need to do the Play Services APK check here too.
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkPlayServices();
}

/**
 * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
 * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
 * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
*/

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The above code is usually added to your app's starting activity, and will prevent your application from crashing (throwing an exception) if that device does not support the use of Google Play Services (which is the case with Amazon's Android-based devices). So the answer to your second question, whether we can get access to Google Plus on Amazon devices, is **NO**.

**References:**

**1.** [Ensure Devices Have the Google Play services APK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure).

**2.** [Check for Google Play Services APK](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-play).

Answer (score 1):

Yey! soon we cant even use Google Analytics on Amazon android devices! we're already limited in Google Drive support, Chrome cast, Locations API. Developing for "Android" and not only"Google" is becoming harder and harder.﻿ Amazon, Google and ebay everyone has its own api for its services.
OR try this.
http://androidcowboy.com/2013/10/add-google-account-kindle-fire-hdx/